# Flutter: update was called on null

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flame

I am trying to make a game with flutter's library Flame. But I am getting this error every time. It is saying that the update is called on null. But I have initialized in the initialize function. I have tried several ways but nothing seems to work. Please help me fix the bug.

```
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'dart:ui';

    import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
    import 'package:flame/game.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/Enemy.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/enemy_spawner.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/heath_bar.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/highscoreText.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/player.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/score_text.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/components/startText.dart';
    import 'package:small_game/states.dart' as gameState;

    class GameController extends Game{
      Random rand;
      Size screenSize;
      double tileSize;
      Player player;
      EnemySpawner enemySpawner;
      List<Enemy> enemies;
      HealthBar healthBar;
      int score;
      ScoreText scoreText;
      SharedPreferences storage;
      gameState.State state;
      HighScoreText highScoreText;
      StartText startText;

      GameController(this.storage){
        initialize();
      }

      void initialize() async{
        rand = Random();
        resize(await Flame.util.initialDimensions());
        player = Player(this);
        state = gameState.State.menu;
        enemies = List<Enemy>();
        enemySpawner = EnemySpawner(this);
        healthBar = HealthBar(this);
        score = 0;
        highScoreText = HighScoreText(this);
        startText = StartText(this);
      }

      @override
      void render(Canvas canvas) {
        Rect background = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        Paint backgroundPaint = Paint()..color = Color(0xffFCFCFA);
        canvas.drawRect(background, backgroundPaint);
        player.render(canvas);
        if(state == gameState.State.menu){
           startText.render(canvas);
           highScoreText.render(canvas);
        } else if(state == gameState.State.playing) {
          enemies.forEach((Enemy enemy) => enemy.render(canvas));
          scoreText.render(canvas);
          healthBar.render(canvas);
        }
      }

      @override
      void update(double t) {
        if(state == gameState.State.menu){
          highScoreText.update(t);
          startText.update(t);
        } else if(state == gameState.State.playing) {
          enemies.forEach((Enemy enemy) => enemy.update(t));
          enemies.removeWhere((Enemy enemy) => enemy.isDead);
          player.update(t);
          scoreText.update(t);
          healthBar.update(t);
          enemySpawner.update(t);
        }
      }

      void resize(Size size){
        screenSize = size;
        tileSize = screenSize.width / 10;
      }

      void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d){
        enemies.forEach((Enemy enemy) {
          if(state == gameState.State.menu){
            state = gameState.State.playing;
          }
          if(enemy.enemyRect.contains(d.globalPosition)){
            enemy.onTapDown();
          }
        });
      }

      void spawnEnemies(){
        double x,y;
        switch(rand.nextInt(4)){
          case 0:
            //TOP
            x = rand.nextDouble() * screenSize.width;
            y = -tileSize * 2.5;
            break;
          case 1:
            //RIGHT
            x = (tileSize * 2.5) + screenSize.width;
            y = rand.nextDouble() * screenSize.height;
            break;

          case 2:
            //BOTTOM
            x = rand.nextDouble() * screenSize.width;
            y = (tileSize * 2.5) + screenSize.height;
            break;
          case 3:
            //LEFT
            x = -(tileSize * 2.5);
            y = rand.nextDouble() * screenSize.height;
        }
        enemies.add(Enemy(this, x, y));
      }

    }
```

My error:

> I/flutter (20131): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY
>   ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter
>   (20131): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during a scheduler
>   callback: I/flutter (20131): The method 'update' was called on null.
>   I/flutter (20131): Receiver: null I/flutter (20131): Tried calling:
>   update(0.0) I/flutter (20131):  I/flutter (20131): When the exception
>   was thrown, this was the stack: I/flutter (20131): #0
>   Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #1      GameController.update (package:small_game/gameController.dart:69:17)
>       I/flutter (20131): #2      GameRenderBox._update (package:flame/game.dart:360:10)
>       I/flutter (20131): #3      GameRenderBox._tick (package:flame/game.dart:353:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #4      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1033:15)
>       I/flutter (20131): #5      SchedulerBinding.handleBeginFrame.
>   (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:951:11)
>       I/flutter (20131): #6      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
>       I/flutter (20131): #7      SchedulerBinding.handleBeginFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:949:17)
>       I/flutter (20131): #8      SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.
>   (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:780:7)
>       I/flutter (20131): #17     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
>       I/flutter (20131): #18     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #19     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
>       I/flutter (20131): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
>       I/flutter (20131): 
>       I/flutter (20131): 
>       I/flutter (20131): This exception was thrown in the context of a scheduler callback. When the scheduler callback was *registered* (as
>   opposed to when the exception was thrown), this was the stack:
>       I/flutter (20131): #0      new _FrameCallbackEntry. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:112:33)
>       I/flutter (20131): #1      new _FrameCallbackEntry (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:115:6)
>       I/flutter (20131): #2      SchedulerBinding.scheduleFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:459:49)
>       I/flutter (20131): #3      GameRenderBox._scheduleTick (package:flame/game.dart:341:50)
>       I/flutter (20131): #4      GameRenderBox.attach (package:flame/game.dart:328:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #5      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.attach (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2886:14)
>       I/flutter (20131): #6      AbstractNode.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/foundation/node.dart:132:13)
>       I/flutter (20131): #7      RenderObject.adoptChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1232:11)
>       I/flutter (20131): #8      RenderObjectWithChildMixin.child= (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2879:7)
>       I/flutter (20131): #9      RenderObjectToWidgetElement.insertChildRenderObject
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1020:18)
>       I/flutter (20131): #10     RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4986:35)
>       I/flutter (20131): #11     RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4752:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
>       I/flutter (20131): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
>       I/flutter (20131): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
>       I/flutter (20131): #15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #16     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
>       I/flutter (20131): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
>       I/flutter (20131): #20     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:998:16)
>       I/flutter (20131): #21     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:969:5)
>       I/flutter (20131): #22     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:915:17)
>       I/flutter (20131): #23     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2328:19)
>       I/flutter (20131): #24     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree
>   (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:914:13)
>       I/flutter (20131): #25     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:795:7)
>       I/flutter (20131): #26     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:845:7)
>       I/flutter (20131): #27     main (package:small_game/main.dart:17:3)
>       I/flutter (20131): (elided 14 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)

Comment: The error is on `gameController.dart:69:17`, can you please provide which line that is from your source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `initialize` function is async, meaning it will run in the background. Therefore when update is first called, `startText` is null and gives you the NPE.  You probably want to add some check on `update` to make sure it's initialized before moving forward with update code, or make `initialize` sync and then do whatever async stuff you need later (since initializing `startText` is certainly not one of them).

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue. I tried wrapping it in an `if statement`, but it didn't work. Posted my question here, if you get a chance to look at it that would be awesome! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282624/flutter-update-is-giving-me-this-error-the-method-was-called-on-null